# nodejs insert postgresql Connection terminated due to connection timeout

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql

i  try to use axios get almost 5000 json insert pg one by one about diffent 5000 table,
postgresql version 14,  but get
Connection terminated due to connection timeout
at D:\stockapp\fineapp\node_modules\pg-pool\index.js:45:11
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
i google this error and search stackoverflow but couldnot find a solve, thanks.
ts code

```
config = {max: 50,    idleTimeoutMillis: 30000,    connectionTimeoutMillis: 2000}
pool = new pg.Pool(this.config);
async poolexe(pa02:string) {
  let client =await this.pool.connect();
  let result =  await client.query(pa02); 
  client.release();
  return  result;  
}
```

```
    expg(pa01: string, pa02: string) {
        let arr = this.spgdb.poolexe(pa02);
        arr.then((result: { rows: any[]; }) =>
            console.log(pa01,'batcher expg success')
        )
            .catch((e: { stack: any; }) => console.error(e.stack)
            );
        
    }
```

```
batch(pa01: string, pa02: any) {
        for (let i = 0; i < pa02.length; i++) {
            this.axio.axurl(pa01, urlsuf[1].surl + pa02[i].scode)
                .then(res => {
                    res.data = this.washer.wajn(pa01, res.data, pa02[i].scode);
                    let sqltxt = pgsql.orin[3].sqlst + pa02[i].scode  + this.trans.transray(res.data);
                    this.expg('end', sqltxt);                    
                }).
                catch((error) => console.log('axios  error' + pa02[i].scode))
        }
 }
```